# PL/SQL script giving errors

Tags: plsql

I've to work on some older EDW scripts, which I think are in PL/SQL and queries fech data from Oracle table as well. But there is some problem with them, the part which declares variables, as shown in the image gives error. I'm unable to understand why?

Below is some part of script,

```
VARIABLE begin_exp_date varchar2(8)
VARIABLE end_exp_date varchar2(8)
VARIABLE begin_cal_key number

Declare
begin
    :begin_exp_date := 'begin_exp_date';
    :end_exp_date := 'end_exp_date';
    :begin_cal_key := 'begin_cal_key';
end;
```

These lines produce error ORA-00900: Invalid SQL statement.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you plug the script in SQL*Plus, it will be executed without the ORA-00900 error. I guess you received the error when it was run in Toad.

Answer (score 0):

If it is indeed PL/SQL, it should be more like this

```
DECLARE
    begin_exp_date varchar2(8);
    end_exp_date varchar2(8);
    begin_cal_key number;
BEGIN
    begin_exp_date := 'begin_exp_date';
    -- and so on
END;
```

You can set constant values to the variables in the `DECLARE` section if you want. Note that you've defined `begin_cal_key` as a `NUMBER` so cannot assign the string `'begin_cal_key'`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this syntax, but the older scripts which I have are also working (no idea which enviornment) with the things mentioned in question. So thought are they ment for any other platform like DB2 or like that?